# Authenticate user across channels in Microsoft bot Framework

Tags: bots, botframework

I want to build a bot which can be used over multiple channels like Skype, Teams, SMS etc. I am using the BotBuilder SDK for this. I would like to authenticate a user across these channels. How do I this without asking him to log in through a web page? Since I am already logged in application (say Skype),how can I fetch the email address or number depending on the context and authenticate implicitly?

If I choose to do this using OAuth, I would require the user to login at every conversation which I do not believe is the right way to go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **Quick answer:**

Every channel is specific and they don't provide a unique way to get information about the user.

You will not have a common information across channels like an email address or an ID, so you will have to build something to do what you want (probably asking the user is the only way...).

---

### Details

More details about what you got in some channels:

- **Facebook Messenger:** `"from": { "id": "1613014XXXXXXXXX", "name": "My Facebook Name" }`

The ID is a `PSID`, for Page Scoped ID. It is not the User ID that you have in the URL of the user profile, it is specific to your Facebook Page hosting your bot

- **Slack:** `"from": { "id": "U54xxxxxx:T53xxxxxx", "name": "nicolas"   }`

The ID is composed of the concatenation of Slack's User ID and Slack's Team ID. The name is my Slack's username

- **Skype:** `"from": { "id": "29:1DwlGVzj.....", "name": "My Skype Name" }`

This ID is a specific to your bot, it is a hash but the way it is generated is not known (not open-source)

- **Skype for Business:** `"from": { "id": "nicolas-r@myCompany.com", "name": "My SkypeForBusiness Name" }`

Here it is easier...

- **Microsoft Teams:** `"from": { "id": "29:1ar5DN....", "name": "Nicolas R" }`

Here it is similar to what we found on Skype, the ID is an unique ID specific to your bot, it is a hash but the way it is generated is not known (not open-source)

- **Twilio SMS:** `"from": { "id": "+33600000000", "name": "+33600000000" }`

The ID is the phone number of the user

==> As you can see, there is a lot to do to get something unique

Comment: Any source for this?

Comment: Source for what? How to know those values?

Comment: Yes, I would be glad to know of any Microsoft documentation link.

Comment: There's no documentation about that as far as I know. I'm giving that based on my experience