# Multiple Slack channel support for botframework

Tags: botframework, slack, azure-bot-service

Currently the botframework allows to register only one slack app.

I have two vendors who would want to use our bot on their slack app... 
which means two slack apps I need to support.

botframework allows me to register only one slack client today. Is there a way to enable registering more than one slack client for the same bot?

Or, any other way multiple slack workspaces can use the bot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be a misunderstanding how Slack apps work.

In general you create one Slack app, which you then install to multiple Slack workspaces. Not the other way around.

According to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-slack?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) you can link your bot to a Slack app. Which you then can install to both Slack workspaces of your two vendors.

Comment: Thanks Erik... due to data security reasons vendor a and vendor b should not see each other data... so, we were using appid to identify the vendor... is there any mechanism to identify which workspace the messages are originating from?

Comment: There is indeed. Each message sent to the bot will contain a team ID which is unique to a Slack workspace. You can use that to identify where each message is coming from and what data they get access to in your bot.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken where can I get the team ID? I couldn't find it in any documentation

Comment: @MartínLaRosa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40940327/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-find-a-slack-team-id-and-a-channel-id

Comment: Thanks @ErikKalkoken, but I meant on the bot side. I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876191/authenticate-user-across-channels-in-microsoft-bot-framework
So I guess checking that the channelId is "slack" and then parsing out the teamID from the userid?

Comment: no, there is an API method for it. Its on the page I linked. Here is the direct link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40941238/4379151